# Is this possible? To load react app form file and run it on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page that does not use react at all.And I was wondering can I use

```
export default function loadJS(url, main, location, tag){
   const scriptTag = document.createElement(tag);
   scriptTag.src = url;

   scriptTag.onload = main;
   scriptTag.onreadystatechange = main;

   location.appendChild(scriptTag);
};
```

To dynamically load reactjs app, append it and run it on page.

How this react app should be build.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try this approach? What happened when it was done? Were there any errors?

Comment: I did not try it. I would like to do something like this. But I don’t know how to get it done.

Comment: Please make an attempt first, then come back with the issues resulting from that attempt?

Comment: I tried it with regular JavaScript and it worked. With react app I don’t know how to start it.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` is usually what starts a react application

Comment: You should try building you react app as a web component so that it can be embedded inside any web page

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrids to convert react app to web component